# shell script won't work in cron

Tags: fedora, cron, database-backup, shell-scripting

I have very smiple script to do a backup, and it is working fine when I run it from the command line, but I am having problems running it as cron job.

My cron entry is this: (running it every minute for testing atm)

```
 * * * * * /var/hosting/ctest/ptest/backup-site.sh > /var/tmp/ctest_ptest_backup_cron2.log
```

And I can see in /var/log/cron that it gets executed

```
Sep 22 11:06:01 devbox CROND[31506]: (gwesio) CMD (/var/hosting/ctest/ptest/backup-site.sh > /var/tmp/ctest_ptest_backup_cron2.log)
```

But it's not doing what it is supposed to do, because backup archive is not created. This is how I have set permissions on the file:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache developers 877 2011-09-22 10:11 /var/hosting/ctest/ptest/backup-site.sh
```

And the script itself is this:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
TIME=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M)
PDIR="/var/hosting/ctest/ptest"
BACKUP_DIR="$PDIR/backups"
BACKUP_FOLDER="$BACKUP_DIR/$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M)"
RESOURCES_DIR="$PDIR/management/html/resources"
sudo mkdir $BACKUP_FOLDER
sudo chown apache:developers $BACKUP_FOLDER
sudo chmod g+w $BACKUP_FOLDER
FILENAME="ctest_ptest-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M).sql"
PTH="$BACKUP_FOLDER/$FILENAME"
ARCHIVE_FILENAME="$BACKUP_DIR/ctest_ptest-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M).tgz"
echo "Database backup script execution"
sudo /usr/bin/mysqldump -uuser -ppassword -hlocalhost --databases ctest_ptest > $PTH
echo "Database dump in $PTH"
echo "Resources backup"
sudo /bin/tar czvfP $ARCHIVE_FILENAME $BACKUP_FOLDER $RESOURCES_DIR > /dev/null
echo "Backup file: $ARCHIVE_FILENAME"
echo "Cleanup"
sudo /bin/rm -r $BACKUP_FOLDER
exit 0
```

I am running out of ideas where to look for any other indications of what could be wrong. I am trying to use absolute paths everywhere as it is suggested in other posts, and script can be executed without any problems from shell script.

I have tried to debug and commented out rm -r line, and noticed that $BACKUP_FOLDER is not being created in the first place, but I have no idea why. I also tried to change crontab to be su - user /var/hosting.... but it didn't help as well.

Maybe it's something obvious I'm missing here, or there are better ways of doing it?
Any ideas?

Greg

Comment: Are you able to the run shell script outside of cron? And what happens then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess cron is not amused by all those `sudo` commands. Remove sudo and run the script from cron as root or at least as a user with necessary prileges to needed directories.

Comment: Cron and sudo work perfectly together... maybe use /usr/bin/sudo

Comment: That was it, removing sudo and running that as root solved my issue. Thanks a lot for a quick response!